# No bower_components installed after clone from github

Tags: node.js, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I'm new to ember-cli, but enjoying it quite a bit.

However, while trying to clone my ember-cli app from my github repository, I ran into trouble.

After cloning, I proceed with `sudo npm install` and `bower install`

`sudo npm install` seemingly works perfectly, but when I run `bower install`, it reflects this error:

```
bower cached        git://github.com/stefanpenner/loader.js.git#1.0.1
bower validate      1.0.1 against git://github.com/stefanpenner/loader.js.git#1.0.1
bower cached        git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims.git#0.0.3
bower validate      0.0.3 against git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims.git#0.0.3
bower cached        git://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader.git#0.0.4
bower validate      0.0.4 against git://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader.git#0.0.4
bower cached        git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers.git#0.0.2
bower validate      0.0.2 against git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers.git#0.0.2
bower cached        git://github.com/components/handlebars.js.git#1.3.0
bower validate      1.3.0 against git://github.com/components/handlebars.js.git#~1.3.0
bower cached        git://github.com/components/ember.git#1.7.0
bower validate      1.7.0 against git://github.com/components/ember.git#1.7.0
bower cached        git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-jj-abrams-resolver.git#0.1.10
bower validate      0.1.10 against git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-jj-abrams-resolver.git#~0.1.7
bower cached        git://github.com/rpflorence/ember-qunit.git#0.1.8
bower validate      0.1.8 against git://github.com/rpflorence/ember-qunit.git#0.1.8
bower cached        git://github.com/dockyard/ember-qunit-notifications.git#0.0.4
bower validate      0.0.4 against git://github.com/dockyard/ember-qunit-notifications.git#0.0.4
bower cached        git://github.com/jquery/qunit.git#1.15.0
bower validate      1.15.0 against git://github.com/jquery/qunit.git#~1.15.0
bower cached        git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11.1
bower validate      1.11.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#^1.11.1
bower cached        git://github.com/components/ember-data.git#1.0.0-beta.11
bower validate      1.0.0-beta.11 against git://github.com/components/ember-data.git#~1.0.0-beta.7
bower cached        git://github.com/dockyard/qunit-notifications.git#0.0.3
bower validate      0.0.3 against git://github.com/dockyard/qunit-notifications.git#~0.0.3
bower cached        git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11.1
bower validate      1.11.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>= 1.7.0 < 2.2.0
bower new           version for git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>= 1.7.0 < 2.2.0
bower resolve       git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>= 1.7.0 < 2.2.0
bower download      https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/2.1.1.tar.gz
bower extract       jquery#>= 1.7.0 < 2.2.0 archive.tar.gz
bower EACCES        EACCES, open '/Users/Iric/.cache/bower/packages/fe2fe255e91d251051d543998aa8327a-2.1.1.lock'

Stack trace:
Error: EACCES, open '/Users/Iric/.cache/bower/packages/fe2fe255e91d251051d543998aa8327a-2.1.1.lock'

Console trace:
Trace
    at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:72:17)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:110:22)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Logger.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:40:20
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44

System info:
Bower version: 1.3.9
Node version: 0.10.29
OS: Darwin 14.0.0 x64
```

From what I can see in the project folder, the bower_component folder is missing completely. I can only assumed that `bower install` didn't work?

Comment: Did you run two instances of `bower` simultaneously? What are the permissions of the file that triggered the error?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, install have failed and something is wrong with the Bower cache.

I would suggest try cleaning it and run the install command again:

```
bower cache clean
bower install
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was an permission access issue.

Once I used

> sudo bower install --allow-root

to install the bower components, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have some right permissions to resolve. Just make your user the owner with the following command:

```
sudo chown -R "your user" /Users/Iric/.cache/bower/
```

It should solve the problem. What you did with

```
sudo bower install --allow-root
```

just delayed the problem. It wasn't a proper solution. Its not recommended to use bower with sudo. I hope it helps you with any future similar problems.